# Singleton constructor separated from get_instance()

Tags: c++, design-patterns, constructor, singleton

In typical singleton the constructor is called when getInstance() is called for the first time. What I need is to have separated init and getInstance functions. The init function must create the instance *using constructor* and the getInstance can only be used if the init function had been called (otherwise it throws an exception). How can I do this?

```
    Singleton::init(required argument); //calls constructor
    Singleton::getInstance(); //only possible if init had been called, otherwise throws exception
```

Comment: Don't use a singleton and problem solved.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Uh-oh. What is the underlying problem that you are truing to solve. It is likely the singleton pattern is not your answer.

Comment: Well, after some thinking I think that I will probably just don't use the singleton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the init method set a bool that says init successful.  In the getInstance method throw the exception if it is false.

You can store it in the class as a static private member.

```
#include <iostream>
class Single
{
public:
    static void init(int x)
    {
        single.number = x;
        inited = true;
    }

    static Single & GetInstance()
    {
        //Do exception stuff here....
        if(inited)
        {
            std::cout << "Inited" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "NOT Inited" << std::endl;
        }
        return single;
    }


    void printTest()
    {
    std::cout << single.number << std::endl;
    }

private:
    Single() : number(5)
    {
        std::cout << "Construction " << std::endl;
    }

    int number;
    static bool inited;
    static Single single;
};

bool Single::inited = false;
Single Single::single;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Entering main" << std::endl;

    Single::GetInstance();
    Single::init(1);
    Single::GetInstance().printTest();

}
```

Program output:

```
Construction 
Entering main
NOT Inited
Inited
1
```

Comment: Yes, but still I have no idea where should I store the static instance of it. I need to call the constructor so that's my problem. That would work if init function is normal member function.

Comment: thanks, but still how can I put the constructor to init method? I think this way I still can't call instance constructor using init().

Comment: @user1873947 I think the misunderstanding is how static works.  The construction of the singleton object happens before main is invoked.  I updated the code to include print statements that should help you understand the ordering.  Your init method, for all intents and purposes, is your constructor.  

As others have said in comments, if you can avoid singletons it is for the best.  They cause scalability issues among other things.